# Deploy Jhipster app with Heroku throws error

Tags: heroku, jhipster

I have deployed this app to heroku but it shows me the next error (attached file)

[image]

also shows me "Application Error"

https://taranapp.herokuapp.com/

What else has to be done to deploy it on heroku?

Comment: I have no idea but seeing  `$PORT` in logs seems to imply that your configuration does not set port property. Did you deploy using the heroku sub generator?  https://www.jhipster.tech/heroku/

Comment: Yes,  I have done it with "jhipster heroku" command, the type of this app is not Monolithic, it's Microservice gateway app.

Comment: OK so you have first deployed a registry as documented?

Comment: OK, to do that in this link https://www.jhipster.tech/heroku/, is the "Deploying Microservices" section?